# How can test third party cookies phaseout be added in edge options in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

Need to automate test third-party cookies phaseout on edge using selenium  3.14

`addArguements` method is not available for this version of selenium in the edge driver

```
options.setCapability(“test-third-party-cookie-phaseout”, true);

driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```